# Limit greenhopper cards to a certain type?

Tags: jira, greenhopper

I want to limit what cards show up in greenhopper views to epics.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes - create a context.
http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/GH/Using+Contexts+to+Filter+and+Highlight+Issues

Francis